# Browser download WOFF and TTF font

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts, webfonts

I have a problem about `@font-face` CSS,
why browser download both WOFF and TTF in some font?

Please Look at below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem

ttf file was corrupt.